# Wifi is not working in HP Envy x360 with Ubuntu

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, hp

I am using HP envy x360 laptop with Ubuntu 16.04. I can use the wired network with Ubuntu, but for some reason I cannot connect to WiFi. What should I do use WiFi with Ubuntu 16.4 ?

I did *rfkill list* and it shows me this information:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no

2: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

I did some research and read some other AskUbuntu answer, but nothing worked.
Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

and reboot.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much for your answer. 

I have question though: I have tried something like this before and after rebooting the machine for some reason my audio stopped working. What can I do if audio doesn't work ?

Comment: Does the audio work now?

Comment: So this solution does not affect audio. If something happens, ask a new question. Do not forget to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with linux kernel which comes with ubuntu 16.04 lts that is 4.4.0 hwe generic, just upgrade your kernel to 4.8 and it solves the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

or

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

and then reboot

----EDIT----

1.5 years later

Something went wrong after a 300 MB software update and I'm facing the same problem again.

Tried long and hard before I gave up and bought TP-Link TL-WN725N 150Mbps Wireless N Nano USB Adapter. Worked right out of the box. All wifi networks fully visible.